# when we click on dropdown than we are not able to scroll the screen and text field is hide behind of keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search, scrollview, dropdown

as you can see in the image I want to scroll the screen but cannot do this when the keyboard is open.
like our search result/ list is hidden behind the keyboard.

---

for this, I am using **SingleChildScrollView**, and it's working when the keyboard or dropdown is not active. when we click on dropdown or edit in the search field then it's not working.

i want to scroll the screen even keyboard is open and search field is active.

[image]

```
ListTileTheme(
                          dense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25),
                          child: Form(
                            key: _formKey,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, right: 25, top: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, bottom: 20),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          "CONTACT",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: AppColor.softBlue,
                                              fontSize: 13,
                                              fontFamily: FontFamily
                                                  .montserratSemiBold),
                                        ),
                                        Spacer()
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),

                            
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ProfileWrapDataWithTitle(
                                        title: "City",
                                      ),
                                      SearchDropdownInputs(
                                        maxHeight: 250,
                                        modes: Mode.MENU,
                                        dropdownHintText: widget
                                                .salesFreshProfileData?.city
                                                .toString() ??
                                            "",
                                        dropdownItem:
                                            _selectCityData!.map((city) {
                                          return city.cityName.toString();
                                        }).toList(),
                                        dropdownOnChanged: (city) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _city = city.toString();
                                            updateCity(city_name: _city);
                                          });
                                        },
                                        dropdownSelectedItem: _city,
                                        dropdownItemSuggestion:
                                            (context, item, isSelected) {
                                          return DropdownSuggestionItem(
                                            dropdownPopup: item.toString(),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ProfileWrapDataWithTitle(
                                        title: "Project",
                                      ),
                                      SearchDropdownInputs(
                                        maxHeight: 250,
                                        modes: Mode.MENU,
                                        dropdownHintText: procheck.toString(),
                                        dropdownItem:
                                            _selectProjectData!.map((project) {
                                          return project.projectName.toString();
                                        }).toList(),
                                        dropdownOnChanged: (pro) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            project = pro.toString();
                                            print(
                                                "this is updated project{$project}");
                                            updatepPro(project_name: project);
                                          });
                                        },
                                        dropdownSelectedItem: project,
                                        dropdownItemSuggestion:
                                            (context, item, isSelected) {
                                          return DropdownSuggestionItem(
                                            dropdownPopup: item.toString(),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ProfileWrapDataWithTitle(
                                        title: "Lead Stage",
                                      ),
                                      SearchDropdownInputs(
                                        modes: Mode.MENU,
                                        maxHeight: 180,
                                        dropdownHintText: "Select Lead Stage",
                                        dropdownItem: _leadStatusConditionData!
                                            .map((leadStatus) {
                                          return leadStatus.statusName
                                              .toString();
                                        }).toList(),
                                        dropdownOnChanged: (leadStatus) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _selectLeadStatus =
                                                leadStatus.toString();
                                            if (_leadStatusConditionData !=
                                                null) {
                                              for (int index = 0;
                                                  index <
                                                      _leadStatusConditionData!
                                                          .length;
                                                  index++) {
                                                LeadStatusCondition
                                                    leadConditionObject =
                                                    _leadStatusConditionData![
                                                        index];
                                                if (_selectLeadStatus ==
                                                    leadConditionObject
                                                        .statusName) {
                                                  leadConditionId =
                                                      leadConditionObject
                                                          .statusId
                                                          .toString();
                                                }
                                                // reason(leadStatus);
                                              }
                                            }
                                            _leadStatusReasonData?.length = 0;
                                            reason(leadStatus);
                                          });
                                        },
                                        // data in this
                                        dropdownSelectedItem: leadStatus =
                                            _selectLeadStatus,
                                        dropdownItemSuggestion: (
                                          context,
                                          item,
                                          isSelected,
                                        ) {
                                          return DropdownSuggestionItem(
                                            dropdownPopup: item.toString(),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  //   ]
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: could you please add full snippet of you code?

Comment: code is added please check

Comment: where did you use SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: I removed it because it's not working.